# Couldn't get to even login screen after updating from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, 17.04

[image]
This is what I'm getting after every boot. What should I do?

Comment: Is there more, or does it just stop there? Report back.

Comment: Yes, it does just stop there

Answer (score 1):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

There was extensive file system corruption during the 16.04 to 17.04 upgrade. So I recommend...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live 17.04 DVD/USB in `Try Ubuntu` mode, and backup your important files
- double-click the `Install Ubuntu` icon on the desktop, and **reinstall** Ubuntu... making sure to **uncheck** the **format** box so it'll keep your /home folders.

Comment: Nahi! It does nothing

Comment: @kern it had to do something... did it show pass #1, 2, 3, etc. or did it show errors?

Comment: Yes, it did.. checked for inode, block and size.. and I pressed yes all the time.. but after reboot.. I'm getting same result

Comment: OK, well, that's not "It does nothing". When you say you "pressed yes all the time", I assume that was in response to errors that it wanted to fix, yes? If so, did you re-run fsck as per my instructions?

Comment: Yes, i did This time it pass 1 to pass 5. /Dev/sda6: 661234/13656064 files(0.4 non-contiguous ), nnn/vvbn blocks

Comment: @kern please see the update in my answer. Report back.